# Sourcemaps don't show original files in CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am using CRA with typescript ( latest version ) and somehow sourcemaps started not showing the original files when debugging.I haven't changed sourcemap related config in webpack.

```
devtool: isEnvProduction
  ? shouldUseSourceMap
    ? 'source-map'
    : false
  : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
```

And currently, when I am debugging, it is showing this version.
[image]

Comment: In chrome
Settings -> Settings (cogwheel) -> Enable "Javascript source maps" and "Allow Devtools to load resources, such as source maps.."